# Unable to Get Lat Lon from PostGIS point table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I am facing issue to get lat/lon from point table. I have two point table with different spatial reference and I am able to get lat/lon from nce_gis_table while I apply same query to another point table with name nce_north_gis_table, I am getting following error

> ERROR:  Argument to Y() must be a point
> SQL state: XX000

[image: Getting error]

[image: I am able to get lat/lon from nce_gis_table]

Comment: check if your 'nce_north_gis_table' geometry is a Point Geometry.

Comment: Please do not present your SQL solely as a picture. This forces anyone who would attempt to reproduce it to type it all in again.

Comment: Yes nce_north_gis_table is a point table

Answer (score 0):

if your geometry of 'nce_north_gis_table' is not a Point Geometry, you could put the "ST_Centroid()" function before calling the "Y()" function, that way you 'force' the point geometry